# How to prompt a confirm message upon quiting the UWP Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, dialog

Objective to achieve:
- Prompt confirm message "**Are you confirm to exit?**", with the options "**Yes**" and "**Cancel**"

I have been finding a way to to achieve the objective written above. I have tried the following code:

```
Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += async (sender, args) =>
{
        args.Handled = true;
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Are you confirm to exit?", "Exit");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CLOSE");            
};
```

the above code i writtin in ***MainPage.xaml.cs***, but this code seem like not working for me, i don't see the "CLOSE" print out in the debug output.

Comment: Where exactly have you put this code? In the constructor?

Comment: @MartinZikmund yes, inside the constructor.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint inside the method to see if it getting hit?

Comment: @MartinZikmund just did what you asked for, I put a breakpoint at the line "args.Handled = true;" and I run the UWP again and click on the "X" button at the title bar, it is not getting hit.

Comment: This is a prime example of a user hostile user interface. The user just actively expressed, that they wish to end the program. There is no conceivable reason to ask them the same question, they already answered. If implemented, this will turn a simple operation into a way more complex sequence of user interrogation. Instead of simply clicking a button, the user is now forced to read additional text, and re-confirm their desire to end the program by clicking another button. The fact that the dialog text isn't even English doesn't help either.

Comment: @IInspectable There's still a chances that user accidentally click on the exit button, so what I trying to do is just to prevent when user accidentally clicked it and the UWP will close immediately.

Comment: If the user closed the application by accident, they will know how to start it again.

Comment: @IInspectable I honestly think your comment sounds more hostile than the message, especially mocking the OP's English skills, which is completely irrelevant. Consider apps like Waze and similar - those always first show a confirmation dialog when you try to exit them - because it does matter if you actually want to close the app completely or just want to hide it, but keep its background operation (in this case navigation) running. We can't know the OP's use case, but it may make sense.

Comment: @Mar: There is no convincing reason to copy poor user interface designs. If a user makes the wrong choice by accident, allow them to recover easily. Forcing a safety guard on all users to prevent the few accidents is highly intrusive.

Comment: @IInspectable There is a very convincing reason... When you have a client who pays you millions a year and they require your program to warn the user that they are closing the window then you do it. You do not tell them it is poor design so tough luck. Have you never had a job before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of digging I have found out that app close confirmation is actually a [restricted capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) that you have to declare in you application manifest. Right-click the `Package.appxmanifest` file in **Solution Explorer** and choose **View code**.

In the opened XML file first add the following namespace in the root `Package` element:

```xml
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
```

And now find the `Capabilities` section where you add the `confirmAppClose` capability:

```xml
<Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />
   <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
</Capabilities>
```

Also, be aware that if you will want to display the `MessageDialog`, you will have to use the deferral, so that the system waits for the `await` to finish before checking the `Handled` property:

```cs
var deferral = e.GetDeferral();           
var dialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit");
var confirmCommand = new UICommand("Yes");
var cancelCommand = new UICommand("No");
dialog.Commands.Add( confirmCommand);            
dialog.Commands.Add(cancelCommand);
dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 1;
if (await dialog.ShowAsync() == cancelCommand)
{
    //cancel close by handling the event
    e.Handled = true;                
}
deferral.Complete();
```

The advantage of this approach compared to just terminating the app manually and setting the event as `Handled` every time is that in this case the app first goes through the suspension lifetime event, which allows you to save any unsaved changes, whereas `Application.Terminate()` for example would mean an immediate "hard-kill" of the app.